# java - variable inside of loop

Tags: java, string, loops

I have just start learning java and I'm sorry if my question is a bit nooby.

Can anyone tell me why this code gives an Error and how to fix it?
thanks

```
static String test = "abc";
static String lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ;
static String re = "" ;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < test.length() ; ++i ) {
        char x = test.charAt(i);
        int f = lower.indexOf(x);
        int h = (f + 2) %26;
        if (h <0) {
            h = h + 26;
        }
        char r = lower.charAt(h);
        String re = re +  r ;       /* here is the problem */

    }

    System.out.println(re);
    }
}
```

output: `The local variable re may not have been initialized`

Comment: You are declaring and initializing it outside the main so the one inside the main doesn't get initialized. Remove the String from there and then it will use the one outside the main which would be at the class level.

Comment: Indent your code properly if you would like people to try and read it.

Comment: just use `re += r;` instead of `String re = re +  r ;`

Comment: A good practice is to call the variables within a method differently from the global ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are re-declaring your `re` variable as a local variable, "shadowing" the `static String re` field declared outside of `main`.

In general, it is not a good idea to make mutable `static` fields, so you should move the declaration of `String re = ""` inside `main()`, and replace `String re = re +  r ;` declaration with `re += r`.

**Note:** Although the above will get your code to work, it is not a good idea to append to a `String` variable inside a loop. You would be better off using a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) object, and calling its `append` method inside the loop:

```
StringBuilder re = new StringBuilder();
for (...) {
    ...
    re.append(r);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You declare a variable at the class level:

```
static String re = "";
```

But then you *re-declare* it in a local scope:

```
String re = re + r;
```

So this line of code (as well as anything else in this scope) is going to try to use *this* variable instead of the class-level one.  In this line of code you reference the variable twice, and that *second* reference is attempting to get a value from the variable.

But this same line is also declaring and setting the initial value *to* the variable.  You can't get a value *before* it's ever been set.  Thus the error.

If you want to use the class-level variable, remove the re-declaration:

```
re = re + r;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code **error: variable re might not have been initialized** because it will only initialized if for loop condition is **true**

Other thing is you try to declare **String re** twice as a static variable outside the method and also inside the method

Not only that, In your code you try to access variable out side it's scope.

```
     class Demo{

     static String test = "abc";
     static String lower = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" ;     
     static String re = "" ; 

     public static void main(String[] args) {

       for (int i = 0 ; i < test.length() ; ++i ) {
           char x = test.charAt(i);
           int f = lower.indexOf(x);
           int h = (f + 2) %26;
           if (h <0) {
              h = h + 26;
           }
           char r = lower.charAt(h);

           re = re +  r ;
    }

     System.out.println(re);
    }
}
```

Read

http://javaseeeedu.blogspot.com/2016/01/local-variable-global-variable-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you look to be declaring the variable 're' twice. One at the class level(static) and once within the method. You can remove the static declaration.

In the code inside main method,
Instead of

```
String re = re + r;
```

try this,

```
string re = "";
re+=r;
```

Comment: I tried this a week before asking here and I showed it to my teacher and he told me to lock it up online because I find it so difficult to understand the difference between python and java in the kind of variable and other stuff

Comment: check out this link: http://www.java67.com/2016/07/how-to-fix-variable-might-not-have-been-initialized-error-in-java.html . You might take some ideas.

Comment: In Java it's `String`, not `string`.  Java is case-sensitive.  Also, why do this in two lines?  The same thing can be done with simply: `String re = r;`  This also serves as a classic demonstration of changing something *only to get the code to compile*, but the code still won't do what the OP actually wants it to do.